# How to expand all items of Rally.ui.tree.Tree in RallyApps SDK2?

Tags: rally

I am using the Tree widget to make everything in our TestPlan more accessible.  I want all the child folders and test cases to be loaded and expanded in the tree.  This is a slow initial load but makes it easy to find the requirement you're looking for and see it in context of our folder hierarchy (we have 3000 test cases in 33 folders).

How can I expand all the folders recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure the tree items to be expanded by default it should auto expand.
http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.tree.TreeItem-cfg-expanded

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
     items: [{
         xtype: 'rallytree',
         treeItemConfigForRecordFn: function(record){
             return {
                 xtype: 'rallytreeitem',
                 expanded: true
             };
         }
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
 });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I saw that config param in the docs but couldn't figure out how to wire it in.